# converting my old script to PDO results do not show?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

ok si im not very fimiliar with PDO im just starting off, could someone help me here why my results will not display? the pages are working but no data would show ..

```
<?php        

require_once 'db/_db.php';  
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM article");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$total_rows = $stmt->rowCount();   

//$allRecords = mysql_query('select * from article');
//$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($allRecords);               

//$base_url = 'https://localhost/pagi/';                //

  global $per_page;                    

  $num_links = 4;                          

  $total_rows = $total_rows;

  $cur_page = 1;         

  if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
      $cur_page = $_GET['page'];

      $cur_page = ($cur_page < 1)? 1 : $cur_page;            //if page no. in url is less then 1 or -ve
    }            
$offset = ($cur_page-1)*$per_page;       //setting offset   
$pages = ceil($total_rows/$per_page);
$start = (($cur_page - $num_links) > 0) ? ($cur_page - ($num_links - 1)) : 1;
$end   = (($cur_page + $num_links) < $pages) ? ($cur_page + $num_links) : $pages;    

  //$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$per_page." OFFSET ".$offset);      

  $stm = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$per_page." OFFSET ".$offset);

  $stm->execute();
  $res = $stm->fetchAll();
  $rows = $stm->rowCount();
  if($rows < 1){
        header("Location: news-events.php");
        exit;
    }    

        if(is_resource($result))
        {       
          foreach( $res as $row ) {               

            $desc = $row["ne_article"];
            $img = $row['ne_image'];
            if(!empty($img)){
            $img = '<br/><img src="uploads/images/'.$img.'" alt="" class="responsive-shrink">';
            }else{
            $img = '';
            }
            $youtube = $row["ne_youtube"];   

            if(!empty($youtube)){
            $youtube = '<br/><div class="video-container"><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$youtube.'"></iframe></div>';
            }else{
            $youtube = '';
            }
            //shortenString($row['ne_article']);
        ?>

            <h4><a href="<?php echo $row['ne_url']; ?>"><?php echo $row['ne_title']; ?></a></h4>

            <h5><b>Views:</b> <?php echo $row['views']; ?>, <b>Posted on:</b> <?php echo format_date($row['created']); ?></h5>                

            <?php echo $img; ?>

            <?php echo $youtube; ?>

            <p>

            <br/><?php echo  bbcode(nl2br(shortenString($desc))); ?>

            </p>

             <div id="pagelink">

                <a href="<?php echo $row['ne_url']; ?>" class="myButton"> Read more...</button></a>
                </div>
        <?php
            }
        }
        ?>


  <div id="pagination">
    <div id="pagiCount">
    <br/><br/>
        <?php

            if(isset($pages))
            {  
                if($pages > 1)       
                {    if($cur_page > $num_links)     // for taking to page 1 //
                    {   $dir = "First";
                        echo '<span id="prev"> <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.(1).'">'.$dir.'</a> </span>';
                    }
                   if($cur_page > 1)
                    {
                        $dir = "Prev";
                        echo '<span id="prev"> <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($cur_page-1).'">'.$dir.'</a> </span>';
                    }                                        

                    for($x=$start ; $x<=$end ;$x++)

                    {                           

                        echo ($x == $cur_page) ? '<strong>'.$x.'</strong> ':'<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
                    }
                    if($cur_page < $pages )

                    {   $dir = "Next";

                        echo '<span id="next"> <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($cur_page+1).'">'.$dir.'</a> </span>';
                    }

                    if($cur_page < ($pages-$num_links) )
                    {   $dir = "Last";                      

                        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$pages.'">'.$dir.'</a> ';
                    }   

                }

            }

        ?>
```

would really appreciate your time and help

Comment: Always check for errors. Do not assume your query is successful.

Comment: yes i have that fixed but still no data displays

Comment: By the way, `$result` is not defined but you check said variable if it is a ressource. `$res` would contain any rows.

Comment: You would have seen that if error reporting were enabled.

Comment: yes i thought so its an array right? so how on earth i fix this m really confused

Comment: An array isn't a ressource.

Comment: so how do i get the resource id in pdo?

Comment: `$stm` is the ressource, but with using `fetchAll` you get all rows in an array, which you save into `$res`.

Comment: so how on earth i fix my above coes to display my records any help please?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing nearly everything wrong. And you did with old mysql as well

To get the number of records in database you should **never select all the rows**, nor fetch them. You have to select the count already.

```
$total_rows = $pdo->query("SELECT count(1) FROM article")->fetchColumn();
```

is how it have to be done with PDO.

Besides, for the other query you should use **prepared statements**.
Finally, you have to take out all the useless verifications and start with `foreach` right away:

```
$stm = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?,?");
$stm->execute([$offset,$per_page]);
$res = $stm->fetchAll();
foreach( $res as $row ) {
```

And read up on setting the error mode properly [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn).

Answer (score -1):

check if you have problem with the quotes... when you echo html code inside ' ' if you have " " and again inside '' like this example echo ' " '' " ' you will have problem. you should use \' in order to avoid these problem  here echo ' '.$dir.' ';

Comment: no with quotes all seems ok as the pagination links are displaying and also working, only the data here are not displaying